# overlay graphs using GPLOT in SAS based on value of a variable

Tags: graph, sas

I have the following code:

```
proc gplot data=work.t1;
symbol line= 1;
plot sales*time;
by region;
run;
```

Using this technique I am getting 3 different graphs for the 3 different regions I have. Can I get all the three graphs in the same graph i.e overlay them ?

Answer (score 0):

To add a third variable, use a plot statement of the form:

```
plot x-var*y-var=z-var;
```

So for your example:

```
proc gplot data=work.t1;
  symbol line= 1;
  plot sales*time=region;
run;
```